# How check in ruby if nested array is empty?

Tags: ruby

Response list returns empty nested array: `[[], [], []]`

How better test with ruby that following nested array is empty?

Comment: All nested arrays or some specific?

Comment: All nested arrays

Comment: How do you define an "empty nested array"? The one you have in your question is most definitely *not* empty, it contains three elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Array#empty?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-empty-3F)

To check all nested arrays are empty with [`Array#all?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-all-3F)

```rb
[[], [], []].all?(&:empty?)
# => true

[[1], [2], []].all?(&:empty?)
# => false

[[1], [2], [3]].all?(&:empty?)
# => false
```

To check at least one nested is empty with [`Array#any?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-any-3F)

```rb
[[], [], []].any?(&:empty?)
# => true

[[1], [2], []].any?(&:empty?)
# => true

[[1], [2], [3]].any?(&:empty?)
# => false
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to handle deeply nested arrays, you probably want to [`flatten`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Array.html#method-i-flatten) your array first:

```
[[], [], []].flatten.empty?
=> true

[[], [[], [[]]]].flatten.empty?
=> true

[[], [[], [[1]]]].flatten.empty?
=> false
```